# Transformations that preserve nearest neighbours order

Tags: graph-theory

Say I have some discrete space $(X,d)$ where $X$ is a finite set and $d$ is a metric. For each $x \in X $ I can find the set of $k$-nearest neighbors with respect to metric $d$.

Is there are any type of transformations (apart from isometries) that preserve the $k$-nearest neighbour **order** for each point?

*Note that the distance is not really that important, just the order.*

Edit: $X$ is a finite set.
(thanks for pointing it out)

Comment: Who are the k-nearest neighbors and in what order do they appear?

Comment: for each $x \in X$ the k-nearest neighbors is a set $\{ y_0, y_1....y_k\} \in X$ of the k-closest points to $x$. They are ordered in such a way that $d(x, y_i) \leq d(x,y_\text{i+1})$

Comment: What are the 2--nearest neighbors of 0 within the real line with the Euclidean metric?

Comment: Thanks for the comment I wasn't very clear in my question, $X$ should be finite.

Answer (score 1):

I think that depends strongly on the particular metric space $(X,d)$ you have. If $X$ is a finite collection of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $d$ is just the standard Euclidean distance, then generically shifting all the points in same random direction by a sufficiently small amount will preserve the nearest neighbor order.

For a specific example, consider the $4$ points $0$, $1$ and $3$ and $8$ on the real axis. You can shift them all around a little bit (up to $1/10$ in either direction should be save) and the order of $k$-nearest neighbors will be preserved (for all $k$ because there are only $3$ neighbors in total).

One can construct examples with countably many points in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Yes my point exactly. I was wondering if there was a empirical way to understand how "little bit" this shift can be. For example, is it enough to be continuous? I don't even believe a homeomorphism (continuous biejction) preserves.